# The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers

Tags: php

I am getting the following error while trying to run a PHP page

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers.

The page was working fine earlier.Then i made some changes to the page for formating of the content(Added some more rows to the HTMLtable and gave some styles for it)

Can anyone tell me why its coming ?

In my local environemnt (WAMP ) its working fine . My Production server is running in an IIS

Answer (score 0):

That means that the error occurred early in the script or that there was a parse error caused by the changes.  Play with your php.ini's error level settings so that errors are printed to the web browser.  I am unsure about ISS logs, but the error may be showing up there.  Beware, though, that having PHP print errors to the web browser makes them world-viewable on an Internet-facing server.